# How to exclude traffic based on geographical location in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, geolocation, reporting

I see a lot of traffic coming from 1 city in a country on which my site is not even focused.

I also know it's not a real user, so I want to exclude all traffic coming from that city in my reports, so that my reports are no longer messed up.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude users in this city from your reports by applying an advanced segment.

1. Click "+ Add Segment"
2. Click "+ New Segment"
3. Name your segment like "Not New York"
4. Select "Demographics"
5. Change the Location to "City" "is not one of "New York"
6. Save the segment
7. Apply this segment to your reports

[image: city segment]

Comment: Perfect! Any way to apply this filter to the real-time reporting as well?

Comment: Is there a way to include or exclude two different cities/regions?

Comment: Not that I know of

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but maybe useful for someone else.

You can permanently remove it by creating a filter.

Go to your account admin page / All filter.

Create a new filter with following parameters:
Filter type: Custom / Exclude
Filter field: Select Country, Region, City or whatever you find suitable. List is quite long and includes fields like IP address, ISP domain etc.

Select views where you want to apply this filter and that's it.

You can also create multiple filters for multiple countries, cities etc.

[image: filter by location]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to exclude multiple cities you must use "does not match regex"
and then use your locations in the regular expression. For example if you want to exclude the city of Boardman Oregon, Ashburn Oregon, and (not set) it would look like this
location city does not match regex
Boardman|Ashburn|(not set)

I just noticed that no one knows you can exclude multiple things on one line if you use a regular expression or regex

Comment: the | or pipe represents "or" in regex